# Staircase like function steps finding

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am making plots for data, and what I get are some staircase-like plots. Data I have is usually like this, for `x` and `y` axis (data given in lists is just an example):

```
x={0.405, 0.41, 0.415, 0.42, 0.425, 0.43, 0.435, 0.44, 0.445, 0.45,
0.455, 0.46, 0.465, 0.47, 0.475, 0.48, 0.485, 0.49, 0.495, 0.5}

y={0.105, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.301, 0.302, 0.305, 0.306, 0.307, 0.4,
0.4, 0.4, 0.465, 0.47, 0.475, 0.48, 0.485, 0.49, 0.495, 0.5}
```

How can I use Mathematica to get all intervals with repeating `y` values with corresponding interval of `x` values for which these repeats happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "*For all pairs* `{xi, yi}`, *select those ones with the* **same** `y`-*value.*":

   `g = GatherBy[Transpose[{x, y}], Last]`

   A typical entry of `g` looks like, eg

   > `{{0.41, 0.2}, {0.415, 0.2}, {0.42, 0.2}}`

   (which is the second entry of `g`, or `g[[2]]`, when using the example data)
2. "*For **every** collection of pairs with the same `y`-coordinate, rearrange the pairs to obtain a list similar to `{{x1, x2, ..., xn}, y0}`*":

   (*the first component of the new list contains the range of `x`-values and the second component is simply the common `y`-coordinate*)

   Define `f = (Transpose[#] &) /* ({#[[1]], #[[-1, 1]]} &)` which simply transposes its argument (*a list of pairs*) and then composes a list with first entry all the `x`'s (`#[[1]]`) and second entry the first of the `y`'s (`#[[-1,1]]`) which is the same as the rest of the `y`'s (because, see question).

   Below, using `f` along with `g` obtained above,

   `Apply[f[{##}]&, g, 1]`

   evaluates to

   > `{
   >    {{0.405}, 0.105}, 
   >    {{0.41, 0.415, 0.42}, 0.2}, 
   >    {{0.425}, 0.301}, 
   >    {{0.43}, 0.302}, 
   >    {{0.435}, 0.305}, 
   >    {{0.44}, 0.306}, 
   >    {{0.445}, 0.307}, 
   >    {{0.45, 0.455, 0.46}, 0.4}, 
   >    {{0.465}, 0.465}, 
   >    {{0.47}, 0.47}, 
   >    {{0.475}, 0.475}, 
   >    {{0.48}, 0.48}, 
   >    {{0.485}, 0.485}, 
   >    {{0.49}, 0.49}, 
   >    {{0.495}, 0.495}, 
   >    {{0.5}, 0.5}
   >   }`

   when we use the data from the example in the question.

In short, defining the following function:

```
sol[x_, y_] := Module[{g, f},
  g = GatherBy[Transpose[{x, y}], Last];
  f = (Transpose[#] &) /* ({#[[1]], #[[-1, 1]]} &);
  Apply[f[{##}] &, g, 1]
 ]
```

and evaluating it, using as inputs `x` and `y` (defined in the questiion) ie `sol[x, y]`, should produce a list, where each entry is itself a list with the first component containing a range of `x` values and the second component containing the common `y` value corresponding to the range of `x` values.

Answer (score 3):

```
KeyValueMap[{#2, #} &]@GroupBy[Transpose[{x, y}], Last -> First]
```

> {{{0.405}, 0.105}, {{0.41, 0.415, 0.42}, 0.2}, {{0.425}, 
>       0.301}, {{0.43}, 0.302}, {{0.435}, 0.305}, {{0.44}, 
>       0.306}, {{0.445}, 0.307}, {{0.45, 0.455, 0.46}, 0.4}, {{0.465}, 
>       0.465}, {{0.47}, 0.47}, {{0.475}, 0.475}, {{0.48}, 
>     0.48}, {{0.485}, 
>       0.485}, {{0.49}, 0.49}, {{0.495}, 0.495}, {{0.5}, 0.5}}